# Having difficulty with JS and z-index for menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a menu in a fixed header and am having difficulty with the way it is displaying. The menu is a set of 4 main links that when clicked will pop up another div that contains more links. The pop up div is set to cover the initial main link and drop down below it -- similar to the horizontal navigation menu for www.huffingtonpost.com .

The problem I'm having is that the .png background image for the drop down menu covers the initial main link that the user clicked on. For instance if a user clicks on the "Research Tools" the resulting pop up menu background covers the "Research Tools" link, keeping the user from being able to see what menu they are currently in.

It also causes some issues with a user trying to click on another main navigational link, like going from having the "Research Tools" menu active and trying to click on the "Instruction Resources" link -- the background image covers part of that link, rendering it almost unclickable. Is there a way to get the 4 main navigational links to stay on top of the pop up menu div?

Here is an image of the issue I'm encountering: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOyKL.jpg

I have tried messing around with the z-index, but nothing seems to work. I've attached the important clips of code in a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gevBe/  if more details are needed, let me know. Here is the javascript portion of what is included in the fiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#toggleLink').on("click", function () {
    $('#showme1').slideToggle(600);
    $('#showme2,#showme3,#showme4').hide(400);
});

$('#toggleLink2').on("click", function () {
    $('#showme2').slideToggle(600);
    $('#showme1,#showme3,#showme4').hide(400);

});

$('#toggleLink3').on("click", function () {
    $('#showme3').slideToggle(600);
    $('#showme1,#showme2,#showme4').hide(400);
});

$('#toggleLink4').on("click", function () {
    $('#showme4').slideToggle(600);
    $('#showme1,#showme2,#showme3').hide(400);
});

$('#toggleLink,#toggleLink2,#toggleLink3,#toggleLink4').on("click", function () {
    $('#cover').show();
});
$('#cover,.button1,.button2,.button3,.button4').click(function () {
    $('#showme1,#showme2,#showme3,#showme4').hide(400);
    $('#cover').hide();
});
});
```

Comment: Using tables for layout went out of use 10 years ago. I would suggest reading some tutorials on modern coding practices.

Comment: Are you basically looking for tabs? If so, are they going to different pages?

Comment: Sort of looking for tabs, the menu design in a pop up tabbed menu. Again, if you check the huffingtonpost.com site, their menus are what I'm aiming for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited your jsfiddle. Check the `#showme2`. Just increased the `top` of it.

I assume you are using z index wrong.
Z-index is used to determine what "layer" the element is on. Say we have two `absolute` or `fixed` positioned elements with `z-index:1` and `z-index:2`. The one with `z-index:1` will be displayed over the one with `z-index:2`.

If your dropdown box covers the initial link you should make it so it appears below the initial link. You can do that by using `top`

```
#yourbox{
top:10px;
}
```

The code above pushes the element with id yourbox 10px **away** from the top.

On a side note, using tables to make a navigation menu is a bit awkward. I *suggest* you use such construction

```
<ul>
<li>Link one</li>
<li>Link two</li>
</ul>

ul li {
display:inline;
}
```

That will give the same result - horizontally positioned elements. Except it looks less clumsy.

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding tables -- will update that portion definitely. The problem still stands, though... I get what you mean about the layers, however the menu design I've been trying to achieve has a portion that covers/highlights the original main navi link. It is hard for me to explain, which is why I referenced the huffington post site, as their menus are almost exactly what I am trying to do. The top portion of the menu box looks like a tab, so the main navi link will look like the title of the tab, with the expanded set of links below it.

Comment: For some reason, when I set the z-index on the table (soon to be set up in the construction you suggested) to 100, the main navi links still show up BEHIND the tab on the pop up menu, instead of on top. The links contained inside the pop up menu still show up fine.

Comment: I suggest you use top to move the popup boxes away from the top so it doesn't matter what displays ontop - they will be in different positions, even if visually colliding.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, however it completely defeats the purpose of the design I was trying to achieve. I know what I'm trying to do can be done, since other sites are using the menu design, I'm just at a loss for how to get the code right. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Look - if you want the popup box to visually be a part of the link that "called" him on click, you set them to both to have the same background color/pattern. There is no need for one box to overlay the other.

Comment: Anyway I found your problem. Your table was not positioned *absolutely* so the z-index didn't work for it.

Comment: If you'd like to better understand what I'm doing, check the image url I added to the original post. Again, I appreciate what you are trying to say, but I'm pretty bent on solving this issue.

Comment: I understand what you are doing. You are doing it wrong. That's an odd way to approach the problem. But it is solved.

Comment: Ah! I missed your second comment last time -- the one regarding positioning the table absolutely and reapplying the z-index. Worked like a charm. Thank you for your help, and I hope you can forgive me for making an arse of myself.